# How would I place an input/select field's ID next to the field (testing purposes)?

Tags: javascript

First: I have a form with multiple input/select fields on it.

On each input/select field etc, I would like to show the ID of that field next to it on the live page so I don't have to inspect each element for its ID while building functionality. Obviously this would be removed when in production, but while in pre-production, it would be very handy.

I am not advanced with JavaScript - so looking for a helping hand/start!

I have tried using this, but obviously I have gone wrong somewhere:

```
function showElementID()
{
    if 
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"), function(inputs) {
    element = document.createElement("span");
    element.textContent = inputs.id;
    inputs.parentNode.appendChild(element);
});

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("select"), function(selects) {
    element = document.createElement("span");
    element.textContent = selects.id;
    selects.parentNode.appendChild(element);
});
}
```

Comment: Can you please add code which you have tried?

Comment: pls add your jsfiddle example code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no javascript required - add the following CSS to your page

```
*[id]:after {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    content:attr(id);
    background:dodgerblue;
    font-size:0.5em;
    padding:2px;
    color:white;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

As pointed out, that wont work on at least input/textarea - if, however all your textareas and inputs have a `<label for="id-of-input">...</label>` you can do the following css

```
*[for]::after {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    content:attr(for);
    background:dodgerblue;
    font-size:0.5em;
    padding:2px;
    color:white;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

any element with an id will now have it's id displayed after it (shouldn't effect flow of page)

Comment: Don’t expect that to work in every browser though – at least not for what was specifically asked here: `input` and `textarea` can not have child elements in HTML – and pseudo element are by definition rendered as if they were a new first/last child element inserted into the element they are applied to; and some browsers “respect” that, and do not render pseudo elements for such elements. (And even though `select` can have children, using pseudo elements might not work on those either.) Apart from that this is of course a very nice solution, +1

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise that caveat on :after/:before - it's a good day when one learns

Comment: This may not be the *perfect* solution, but it's about as quick and easy as it comes. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Quick&dirty jQuery version:

```
$('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
    $(this).after($('<span/>').text(
     ($(this).attr('id') ? '#' + $(this).attr('id') : '[no id]')
    ));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q64oLm3L/1/

Comment: You can of course add a class to the span element, and then position it absolutely via that (see Jaromanda X’s answer, from which I shamelessly borrowed the styles), if you don’t want those inserted elements to disrupt document flow: http://jsfiddle.net/q64oLm3L/2/